# How to apply conditional formatting for multiple cells based on a range of cells

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have a list of names in column A
I have a list of names in column B determined by formula.

I was the specific name to turn green in column A if it is present anywhere in column B.

e.g. 
A - 10 names, only 3 are "drivers" 
B - I type driver names and other names as I 'fill the cars' with people. I want the name in column A to turn green when I type it in column B so I know they've been sorted.

Working in google docs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I dont have code... hence the question lol

Comment: You mean that you summoned up the collective wisdom of Stack Overflow when you hadn't tried *anything* yet?

Answer (score 0):

Click on cell `A1`. Then choose *Conditional Formatting* -> *New Rule* from the menu.

Choose the option *"Use a formula to determine which cells to format"*.

Type the following formula into the box:

```
= (SUMPRODUCT((A1=B:B)+0))>0
```

Click the *"Format..."* button to set the color to green.

Click *OK*.

[image]

Under *"Applies to"*, type in your range of cells in column `A` where you want the conditional formatting to apply.

See below example that shows this conditional formatting applied to cells `A1` to `A4`. Notice how any name in column `A` that appears anywhere in column `B` is green.

[image]