# Formatting cell if any of the sub-cells contain

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I couldn't find an answer to my question anywhere, so I am asking here:

In column A, I have cells of different size -->
In column B, I have then cells that are subcells of A.

So

```
A1 contains B1,B2,B2
A2 contains B3
A3 contains B2,B3 
...
```

How can i convert the cells in column A with the condition that any
of its subcells contains a certain value?

I tried a simple `=IF()` but that won't work, because the cells in A are 
of different size.

Thank you very much

Comment: There's no such thing as "subcells" in excel so I don't know what you mean by that. Can you please show a screenshot of your data?

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to look up Conditional Formatting. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603524/how-to-apply-conditional-formatting-for-multiple-cells-based-on-a-range-of-cells/46604220#46604220) for example.

Comment: also worth noting that in Excel, columns are letters and rows are numbers.